# Java code to download a file(attachment) that I get in response after hitting a Soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, download

I am calling a soap web service in java and I am getting an attachment in response I get the name of the attachment and I want a java code to download and save that file to a specific location in my local machine ... Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have access that service in local machine you can access, but you have logon to particular remote server to download the file.

If you got any attachment response for file you can easily download the file by using below code

```
if(attachmentsResp!=null)
{
    for(int j=0; j<attachmentsResp.length; j++)
    {
        if(attachmentsResp[j].getContent()!=null)
        {
            //getting the file to particular Driver Name(C drive ,D drive)
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Driver Name:"+attachmentsResp[j].getName()+"."+attachmentsResp[j].getFileType());
        }         
    }
}
```

If you want decode to file download let me know.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response .. I get the xml response of the web service and I am not sure whether it comes with an attachment or not but I have been told it does and have to download it store it in a drive on my machine..

Comment: Ill be able to share tomorrow.. Will that be ok?

Comment: it's ok not a problem

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:downloadDocInFileResponse xmlns:ns="http://provider.ws.jts.omni.newgen.com">
         <ns:return>
            <swa:fileName xmlns:swa="http://provider.ws.jts.omni.newgen.com">
               <swa:graph>urn:uuid:88FA843D74D2FD8D941452839953018</swa:graph>
               <swa:message>file download on server successfully</swa:message>
            </swa:fileName>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:downloadDocInFileResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

```
1.  Login to the server by providing the server url and authentication credentials.
2.  Create the request object GetFileAttachmentRequestType for the getFileAttachment operation
3.  Create an array of requests of type SoapGetFileAttachmentRequestType. Batch operations may be
4.  performed by populating as many request objects as required to retrieve several files
5.  with one single operation. 
6.  For each batched request, specify the unique object from whose attachment tab
7.  files shall be retrieved. Supply class identifier and object number information
8.  for the same. 
9.  The exact specification of the attachment to be downloaded is defined as an
10. object of type SoapFileAttachmentRequestType. This object includes information
11. about rowId, a boolean to indicate whether all the files of the object are to
12. be downloaded and finally provision for fileIds to be used in special cases.  
13. In this sample the boolean element 'allFiles' is set to true. By using this 
14. option, the necessity to derive rowIds or fileIds is negated. The response
15. object will consist of all the files present in the attachment tab of the 
16. soap object specified in the request.          
17. The request objects are set and the soap Stub is used to make the getFileAttachment
18. webservice call. The status code obtained from the response object is printed to
19. verify the success of the getFileAttachment operation. 
20. If the status code is not 'SUCCESS', then populate the list of exceptions
21. returned by the webservice. 
22. If the webservice call was successful, then display information about the file(s) retrieved.
```